# ESP32-CAM not sending base64 string as HTTP post request

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, http

in my recent project, I'm trying to detect motion and capture an image using the esp32 cam module and send it to the server via HTTP.

Once the image is captured it is converted to a base64 string and while trying to send the data at the server the body of the HTTP request is empty i.e., the base64 string is not sent.

Code that sends the image

```
void sendPic(String data, String len) {

    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {

      HTTPClient http;

      http.begin("http://192.168.1.35:8000/capture");  
   
      String d = data ;
    
      int res_c = http.POST(d);
      
      if(res_c > 0){
        Serial.println(res_c);
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("Not sent");
        Serial.print(res_c);
      }
      http.end();
    }
}
```

Entire code

```
// turn on debug messages
#define VERBOSE
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <base64.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "EloquentSurveillance.h"


const char* ssid = "****";
const char* password = "********";


void sendPic(String data, String len) {

    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) 

      
      HTTPClient http;

      http.begin("http://192.168.1.35:8000/capture");  
   
      String d = data ;
    
      int res_c = http.POST(d);
      
      if(res_c > 0){
        Serial.println(res_c);
      }
      else{
        Serial.println("Not sent");
        Serial.print(res_c);
      }
      http.end();
  
    }
}

/**
 * Instantiate motion detector
 */
EloquentSurveillance::Motion motion;


/**
 *
 */
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.println("Connecting");
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
      HTTPClient http;
      int res_c = -1;
      while(res_c < 0){
        http.begin("http://192.168.1.35:8080/capture");
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        String test = "hello from esp32";
        res_c = http.POST(test);
      
        if(res_c > 0){
          Serial.println(res_c);
        }
        else{
          Serial.println(res_c);
        }
        http.end();
      }
      
    }
    

    delay(3000);
    debug("INFO", "Init");

    /**
     * See CameraCaptureExample for more details
     */

    camera.aithinker();
    camera.vga();
    camera.bestQuality();

    /**
     * Configure motion detection
     *
     * > setMinChanges() accepts a number from 0 to 1 (percent) or an integer
     *   At least the given number of pixels must change from one frame to the next
     *   to trigger the motion.
     *   The following line translates to "Trigger motion if at least 10% of the pixels
     *   in the image changed value"
     */
    //motion.setMinChanges(0.015);
    motion.setMinChanges(0.02);

    /**
     * > setMinPixelDiff() accepts an integer
     *   Each pixel value must differ at least of the given amount from one frame to the next
     *   to be considered as different.
     *   The following line translates to "Consider a pixel as changed if its value increased
     *   or decreased by 10 (out of 255)"
     */
    motion.setMinPixelDiff(5);

    /**
     * > setMinSizeDiff() accepts a number from 0 to 1 (percent) or an integer
     *   To speed up the detection, you can exit early if the image size is almost the same.
     *   This is an heuristic that says: "If two consecutive frames have a similar size, they
     *   probably have the same contents". This is by no means guaranteed, but can dramatically
     *   reduce the computation cost.
     *   The following line translates to "Check for motion if the filesize of the current image
     *   differs by more than 5% from the previous".
     *
     *   If you don't feel like this heuristic works for you, delete this line.
     */
    //motion.setMinSizeDiff(0.015);
    motion.setMinSizeDiff(0.02);

    /**
     * Initialize the camera
     * If something goes wrong, print the error message
     */
    while (!camera.begin())
        debug("ERROR", camera.getErrorMessage());

    debug("SUCCESS", "Camera OK");
}

/**
 *
 */
void loop() {
    /**
     * Try to capture a frame
     * If something goes wrong, print the error message
     */
    if (!camera.capture()) {
        debug("ERROR", camera.getErrorMessage());
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Look for motion.
     * In the `true` branch, you can handle a motion event.
     * For the moment, just print the processing time for motion detection.
     */
    if (!motion.update())
        return;

    if (motion.detect()) {
        debug("INFO", String("Motion detected in ") + motion.getExecutionTimeInMicros() + " us");
        String encoded = base64::encode(camera.getBuffer(), camera.getFileSize());
        int size = camera.getFileSize() + 50;
        sendPic(encoded, (String)size);
        delay(4000);
    }
    else if (!motion.isOk()) {
        /**
         * Something went wrong.
         * This part requires proper handling if you want to integrate it in your project
         * because you can reach this point for a number of reason.
         * For the moment, just print the error message
         */
        debug("ERROR", motion.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner in using esp32 cam any guidance on how to achieve the objective will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ESP32-CAM not sending base64 string as HTTP post request`  ... what is it sending? ... how is it sending it?

Comment: Hi @jsotola the request is received at the server when I print the request in the console it contains only the headers and the body is empty. I checked it with wireshark as well.

Comment: Have you checked it *before* it's sent? Try outputting the body in your code everywhere you pass it through the code - like right after the data is encoded and just before it's posted. Also there's absolutely no need to do ` String d = data ;`, all that's doing is making an extra unneeded copy of the data, which given the limited memory on the ESP32 is not great.

Comment: Hi @romkey I actually did print the encoded data before it was sent and the string was printed. And I just added the line because while debugging I tried adding a prefix to see whether it went through but no either way.